# Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0035i000008hdheAAA; first error: DELETE_FAILED

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, custom-controller, salesforce-classic

[image]

I am coming across the above error while deleting a record from the database.

The vf page code is as follows

```
<apex:page controller="EditAll">
    <apex:form >
         <apex:sectionHeader title="Edit Contacts for" subtitle="{!c[0].Account.Name}"/>
        
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNumber" />
            <apex:outputPanel id="panelWithVar">
                <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNumber" />
            </apex:outputPanel>
            
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!SaveMethod}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!CancelMethod}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!c}" var="t" id="newItems">
                <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                    <apex:OutputField value="{!t.Name}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Title">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!t.Title}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Email">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!t.Email}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Phone">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!t.Phone}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Amount">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!t.Amount__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:commandButton value="Remove" action="{!RemoveMethod}" reRender="newItems,panelWithVar">
                        <apex:param name="p1" value="{!rowNumber}" assignTo="{!numberOfRowToRemove}"/>
                    </apex:commandButton>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                        <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!rowNumber + 1}" />
                </apex:column>
                
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The apex class is as follows:

```
public class EditAll 
{
    public String ids{set;get;}
    public List<Contact> c {set;get;}
    public Integer numberOfRowToRemove {set;get;}
    public Contact d;
    
    public EditAll()
    {
        ids=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        c = new List<Contact>([select Name, Title, Email , Id, Phone, Amount__c, accountid, Account.Name from contact where accountid=:ids]);
        
    }
    
    public PageReference SaveMethod()
    {
        update c;
        return new PageReference('/'+ids);
    }
    
    public PageReference CancelMethod()
    {
        return new PageReference('/'+ids);
    }
    
    public PageReference RemoveMethod()
    {    
        id rid = c.get(numberOfRowToRemove).id;
        c.remove(numberOfRowToRemove);
        delete [select id from Contact where id=: rid];
        update c;
        return null;
      
    }
    
    
}
```

Could anyone please let me know how can i resolve the above error, or where can I make the code changes to get the error resolved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your image says the following: "Your attempt to delete Ms Lauren Boyle could not be completed because it is associated with the following cases 00001024, 00001025"

you can't delete a contact that has related records, delete those two cases first, and then try again. If it has no more related records, the contact will be deleted without problems